# Android Studio tcp client connect to c# server

Tags: java, c#, android, sockets, tcp

i started with android a short time ago. This time i tried to connect a c# tcp server with a java tcp client. To debug i worte a c# client and server and if i use the c# client to talk to the server, there is no problem. But my java socket has problems with connecting. I copied the java tcp code for example from the net.

c# code:

```
namespace MTCliserv2
{
  class MTCliserv2
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      string txt;

      Console.Write("MTCliserv2 Server or Client (s/c): ");
      txt = Console.ReadLine();

      if (txt == "s")
        Server();
      else
        Client();

      Console.Write("\nHit any Key to continue "); Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static IPAddress GetIPAddress()
    {
      IPAddress ipAdr = Dns.Resolve("localhost").AddressList[0];
            ipAdr = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.1");

            return ipAdr;
    }

    static void Server()
    {
      TcpListener server;
      Socket socke;
      IPAddress ipAdr = GetIPAddress();
      try
      {
        server = new TcpListener(ipAdr, 13);
        server.Start();
        Console.WriteLine("Server {0} gestartet", server.LocalEndpoint);
        while (true)
        {
          socke = server.AcceptSocket(); // Aufruf blockiert!!
          mit diesem Client abwickelt
          new ConnTalk(socke);
        }
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
        Console.WriteLine("Error {0}", e);
      }
    }

    static void PrintConnectionInfo(Socket aSock)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Anfrage von {0}", aSock.RemoteEndPoint);
    }

    static void Client()
    {
      const string serverName = "localhost";

      try
      {

        TcpClient client = new TcpClient("192.168.1.1", 13);
        NetworkStream strm = client.GetStream();
        Socket sc = client.Client;
        StreamReader strmRd = new StreamReader(strm);
        StreamWriter strmWr = new StreamWriter(strm);
        string txt, txt2;

        Console.WriteLine("Connected to {0}", sc.RemoteEndPoint);
        while (true)
        {
          Console.Write("Msg= ");
                    txt = Console.ReadLine();
          if (txt == "end")
            break;
          strmWr.WriteLine(txt); strmWr.Flush();

          txt2 = strmRd.ReadLine();
          Console.WriteLine("Answer: {0}", txt2);
        }


        client.Close(); strmRd.Close(); strmWr.Close();
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
      }
    }
  }


  // Pro Verbindung wird 1 ConnTalk-objekt erzeugt
  class ConnTalk
  {
    Thread m_Thr;
    Socket m_Sc;

    public ConnTalk(Socket aSc)
    {
      m_Sc = aSc;
      m_Thr = new Thread(this.TalkWithClient);
      m_Thr.Start();
    }

    void TalkWithClient()
    {
      NetworkStream strm = new NetworkStream(m_Sc);
      StreamReader strmRd = new StreamReader(strm);
      StreamWriter strmWr = new StreamWriter(strm);
      string txt;

      Console.WriteLine("Talking with {0}", m_Sc.RemoteEndPoint);
      try
      {
        while (true)
        {
          txt = strmRd.ReadLine();
          Console.WriteLine("Msg: {0}", txt);
          txt += " Echo!! \r\n";
          strmWr.Write(txt); strmWr.Flush();
        }
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception in TalkWithClient");
      }

      Console.WriteLine("{0} Disconnected", m_Sc.RemoteEndPoint);

      m_Sc.Close(); strm.Close(); strmRd.Close(); strmWr.Close();
      return;
    }
  }
}
```

And here is the java code:

```
package com.example.mogri.tcpsocket;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText ettext;
    private TextView tvlog;

    TcpClient mTcpClient;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if ( ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.INTERNET) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.INTERNET},225);
        }


        if ( ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE},225);
        }

        ettext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etText);
        tvlog = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tVlog);

        Button btnsend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnsend);


        btnsend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String input = ettext.getText().toString();
                mTcpClient.sendMessage(input);
                log(input);

            }
        });

        new ConnectTask().execute("");

    }

    public void log(String add){
        tvlog.setText( tvlog.getText()+"\n"+add);
    }


    public class ConnectTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, TcpClient> {



        @Override
        protected TcpClient doInBackground(String... message) {

            //we create a TCPClient object
            mTcpClient = new TcpClient(new TcpClient.OnMessageReceived() {
                @Override
                //here the messageReceived method is implemented
                public void messageReceived(String message) {
                    //this method calls the onProgressUpdate
                    publishProgress(message);
                }
            });
            mTcpClient.run();

            return null;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
            //response received from server
            Log.d("test", "response " + values[0]);
            //process server response here....

        }

    }

}
```

The tcpclient class:

```
package com.example.mogri.tcpsocket;

import android.util.Log;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;

/**
 * Created by mogri on 01.04.2017.
 */

public class TcpClient {

    public static final String SERVER_IP = "192.168.1.1"; //server IP address
    public static final int SERVER_PORT = 13;
    // message to send to the server
    private String mServerMessage;
    // sends message received notifications
    private OnMessageReceived mMessageListener = null;
    // while this is true, the server will continue running
    private boolean mRun = false;
    // used to send messages
    private PrintWriter mBufferOut;
    // used to read messages from the server
    private BufferedReader mBufferIn;


    public TcpClient(OnMessageReceived listener) {
        mMessageListener = listener;
    }

    public void sendMessage(String message) {
        if (mBufferOut != null && !mBufferOut.checkError()) {
            mBufferOut.println(message);
            mBufferOut.flush();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Close the connection and release the members
     */
    public void stopClient() {

        mRun = false;

        if (mBufferOut != null) {
            mBufferOut.flush();
            mBufferOut.close();
        }

        mMessageListener = null;
        mBufferIn = null;
        mBufferOut = null;
        mServerMessage = null;
    }

    public void run() {

        mRun = true;

        try {
            //here you must put your computer's IP address.
            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);

            Log.e("TCP Client", "C: Connecting...");

            //create a socket to make the connection with the server
            Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVER_PORT);

            try {

                //sends the message to the server
                mBufferOut = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);

                //receives the message which the server sends back
                mBufferIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));


                //in this while the client listens for the messages sent by the server
                while (mRun) {

                    mServerMessage = mBufferIn.readLine();

                    if (mServerMessage != null && mMessageListener != null) {
                        //call the method messageReceived from MyActivity class
                        mMessageListener.messageReceived(mServerMessage);
                    }

                }

                Log.e("RESPONSE FROM SERVER", "S: Received Message: '" + mServerMessage + "'");

            } catch (Exception e) {

                Log.e("TCP", "S: Error", e);

            } finally {
                //the socket must be closed. It is not possible to reconnect to this socket
                // after it is closed, which means a new socket instance has to be created.
                socket.close();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

            Log.e("TCP", "C: Error", e);

        }

    }

    //Declare the interface. The method messageReceived(String message) will must be implemented in the MyActivity
    //class at on asynckTask doInBackground
    public interface OnMessageReceived {
        public void messageReceived(String message);
    }

}
```

Comment: "... my java socket has problems with connecting." What problems?

Comment: I checked the programm a secound time. And with some try catch routines i found the error. I had no permissions for the internet!

Comment: I dont understand how that could happen, to prevent that i used these:   if ( ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.INTERNET) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.INTERNET},225);
        }